# React-select v2 bundle size

Tags: react-select

My webpack bundle size has increased by 52KiB when upgrading react-select from 1 -> 2. Is this correct or am I possibly doing something wrong? Could this be caused by the css-in-js change in the library? Following on from that, is there a way to extract that via webpack into it's own css file?